# Inserting entity to google cloud datastore using REST API

Tags: google-cloud-datastore

Trying to use rest api for google datastore (unfortunately there is no client library for c++).
Got stuck on inserting an entity.

Reading [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/reference/rest/), which is unfortunately not very good (at least for REST).
It doesn't tell what is the URI, so I am guessing it is the following:

POST https://datastore.googleapis.com/v1/projects/{projectId}:Entity

but unfortunately I get a reply:
The requested URL `/v1/projects/my_project_id:Entity` was not found on this server.

Anyone out there is/was using it?
Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Managed to find the answer. Entity is an object. Correct api call is projects.commit:

```
POST https://datastore.googleapis.com/v1/projects/{projectId}:commit
```

And then in the json object I need to pass insert mutation.

Somehow misunderstood the terminology, thought commit is needed after you do actual insert.

[Here is the actual documentation link.](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects/commit)